# How to align views by the widest?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, right-align

how to create android layout that labels fill be aligned (right). I do not want to set width manually, to preserve space. Left column has to be as small as the widest label. Right column fill the rest of parent.

Something like this (underscores added only to format it here):
_______**Label:** Value of label_________________
____**Big label:** Value of big label______________
**Another label:** Value of another label__________
______**Label2:** Value of label 2_______________

Problem is that I do not know which label is the widest, so I do not know to which one to bind the others. Iam not care about linear or relative layout... just suggest the easiest solution. Thanks

Comment: You need to make use of TableLayout, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html, and make the column width take width of largest child

Comment: @AnkitBansal: oh, I did not know there is such layout. Sounds promising, will try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        -

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="first_name"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="user_dob"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="user_gender"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_patient_detail_values"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="12/22/1978"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="M"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_weight, following example is showing that 1/3 space occupy by first label, and other whole space by second.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="abc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="abc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:weightSum="3"  is amount of your screen size  you can change it
let suppose i made screen of size android:weightSum="10", now divide your space according to ...